# What is the norm of v + w

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

So the norm of v is defined as ||v|| = sqrt(v_1^2+...+v_n^2)

I would guess that the norm of v+w is defined as ||v+w|| = sqrt((v_1+w_1)^2+...+(v_n+w_n)^2)

Is this correct? My textbook asks me to prove that ||v+w|| <= ||v|| + ||w||, which I'm having trouble doing with these definitions.

For example,

```
||v+w||^2 
= (v_1+w_1)^2 + ... + (v_n+w_n)^2 
= v_1^2 + ... + v_n^2 + w_1^2 + ... + w_n^2 + 2 (v_1*w_1 + ... + v_n*w_n)
and
||v||^2 + ||w||^2
= v_1^2 + ... + v_n^2 + w_1^2 + ... + w_n^2
```

So in order to prove that ||v+w|| <= ||v|| + ||w||, v_1*w_1 + ... + v_n*w_n must be <= 0, which doesn't make sense to me.

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Have you proved the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality?

Comment: The Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality is proved immediately after this exercise.

Comment: Do they use this exercise to prove that? Because the easiest way to prove this norm inequality is by using Cauchy-Schwartz. In fact, Cauchy-Schwartz practically stares you in the face when you try to prove this.

Comment: Here is the proof provided in the book: `Proof. Let λ be a real number. Then
0 ≤ <v − λw, v − λw> = <v, v> − <v, λw> − <λw, v> + <λw, λw>
= ||v||^2 − 2λ<v, w> + λ^2||w||^2
This is a quadratic polynomial in λ which is always greater than or equal to 0. For this inequality to
hold, the discriminant of this quadratic must be nonpositive. That is, we must have, in the usual notation,
b^2 − 4ac ≤ 0. With a = ||w||^2
, b = −2<v, w>, and c = ||v||^2
, we get our desired inequality immediately` I see that the -2*lambda*<v,w> is very similar to my 2*<v,w> but am not sure what to make of this.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to square both sides of the inequality $\|v+w\|\le \|v\|+\|w\|$ in order to prove it. But you should do it correctly:
$$\|v+w\|^2\le \|v\|^2+\|w\|^2+2\|v\|\,\|w\| \tag{1}$$
In your computation, the last term is missing.

After simplification, (1) becomes $2\langle u,v\rangle\le 2\|v\|\,\|w\|$, i.e., the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.